# Facebook login shows popup two times on iOS 11

Tags: ios11, facebook-sdk-4.x

I tested Facebook login by double tap on Login button, but it shows confirmation popup two times as below gif.
If I tap multiple times quickly, that popup shows no more than 2 times.
How to prevent that issue?. I just want that popup show only one time.
FacebookSDK version is 4.31.1. (That function works well on iOS 10.3)
 Thank you so much.

[FacebookLogin show Popup double times](https://media.giphy.com/media/vbQmHj2ond7n0gyE07/giphy.gif)

Comment: you are double tapping the button ?

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz yes, I double tapped the button.

Comment: why? swift buttons work on single tap. why are you double tapping the button ?

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz I just test it. If user accidentally double tap on button, it will be bad UX.